# Retagging after an answer is given

Tags: discussion, etiquette, retagging

Sometimes a question is asked under a perfectly suitable tag, but is given an answer which is addresses respects strongly related to other tags.

What should be the proper etiquette regarding retagging the question?

Obviously when there are many answers addressing the question within the confines of the original tags, there is no need to retag. What happens when there is only one answer, or even no other?

Is it correct to retag to question and add/replace the tags?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tags should help in finding information.

If a certain tag on a question would help finding information presented in one of it answers, then the tag itself would be useful.

Of course, if a question attracts 32 answers from all domains of mathematics... well, good sense is always good to have! :)

Comment: That is a  very good point.

Comment: correct; answers that wildly change the tags necessary on the question imply that something is deeply wrong with the question to begin with...

Comment: Answers that wildly change the tags necessary on a question may imply that two branches of mathematics are far more closely related than one might reasonably have thought.

Comment: @GerryMyerson **cough** Reimann Hypothesis **cough**

Answer (score 9):

Generally, I agree with what's been said, but there is one thing to keep in mind, which I think is best summarized by a comment on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1):

> tagging this question [cauchy-sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cauchy-sequences) is about as useful as tagging the question "What's the best color for a Porsche?" as [combustion-engine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combustion-engine).

(I tag-ified the tags in the quote here, as the tag-link syntax was not available at the time.)

As long as the tags are still related to the question and not just to some specific corner of an answer, retagging to better organize things or to make things more findable is good.